# Power BI is missing Google Sheet connector

Tags: google-sheets, powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

Power BI provides the [Google Sheet connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/connectors/google-sheets) which is no more in Beta version and should be available on any lates Power BI version.

On my laptop I'm running the version `2.114.664.0 64-bit (February 2023)` and I have updated Power BI also on the same version on our [VDI](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/virtual-desktop) so every employer can work on the same version of Power BI.

The problem is that the Google Sheet connector is present on my laptop but not on the Power BI, same version, on the VDI:

[image]

So, same version, but on the VDI is missing.

I go to search online and I find out that the problem might be related to missing [Preview features](https://speckle.community/t/powerbi-connector-not-showing-up/2076/6) or [Security](https://speckle.community/t/powerbi-connector-not-showing-up/2076/7).

But I have ticket all options both in Preview feature and Security and after restarting Power BI the Google Sheet connector is still missing.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Is power Bi for Excel? Also, if something existed in Beta does that guarantee it getting into the final version?

Comment: Hi @SolarMike , The Google Sheet connector is no more in Beta version (see picture). I don't need Power BI for Excel but for Google Sheet

Comment: Gooigle search: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Power_BI Why would Microsoft want to improve Googlesheets?

Comment: To have more data source. In fact Google Sheet is not the only non-Microsoft data source. If you dig in the Power BI data source you can find a bit of everything: IBM, Oracle, SAP, Salesforce, Google, Amazon, etc...

Comment: I will ask to reinstall. I will update you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried reinstalling on the VDI?

The UI is just a shortcut for the following. Paste the following code into a blank query in Power Query and substitute your sheet name and url.

```
let
    Source = GoogleSheets.Contents("https://sheeturl"),
    Sheet1_Table = Source{[name="Sheet1",ItemKind="Table"]}[Data]
in
    Sheet1_Table
```

Comment: Hello David, it's not working: https://snipboard.io/42Ag0P.jpg

Comment: I think I need the connector anyway: https://snipboard.io/QbFkwj.jpg

Comment: BTW, I tested on my laptop and your code is working: I can connect to Google sheet. But your code needs the connector, and when that is missing.... no joy

Comment: Fair enough. It is definitely installed as part of the Feb release.